# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: AppKey cannot be null or empty error in android

Tags: android, illegalargumentexception

I am trying to run the android code from the following [url](https://github.com/Appdynamics/ECommerce-Android).

This is the error I am getting. I did not make any changes in the code. Could any help me in rectifying this error.

```
10-25 14:25:04.083 3438-3438/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
10-25 14:25:04.254 3438-3438/com.appdynamics.pmdemoapps.android.ECommerceAndroid D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
10-25 14:25:04.264 3438-3438/com.appdynamics.pmdemoapps.android.ECommerceAndroid E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-25 14:25:04.264 3438-3438/com.appdynamics.pmdemoapps.android.ECommerceAndroid E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.appdynamics.pmdemoapps.android.ECommerceAndroid, PID: 3438
10-25 14:25:04.264 3438-3438/com.appdynamics.pmdemoapps.android.ECommerceAndroid E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create application com.appdynamics.pmdemoapps.android.ECommerceAndroid.CustomApplication: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: AppKey cannot be null or empty
10-25 14:25:04.264 3438-3438/com.appdynamics.pmdemoapps.android.ECommerceAndroid E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4641)
10-25 14:25:04.264 3438-3438/com.appdynamics.pmdemoapps.android.ECommerceAndroid E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:155)
10-25 14:25:04.264 3438-3438/com.appdynamics.pmdemoapps.android.ECommerceAndroid E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1378)
10-25 14:25:04.264 3438-3438/com.appdynamics.pmdemoapps.android.ECommerceAndroid E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
10-25 14:25:04.264 3438-3438/com.appdynamics.pmdemoapps.android.ECommerceAndroid E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
10-25 14:25:04.264 3438-3438/com.appdynamics.pmdemoapps.android.ECommerceAndroid E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5343)
10-25 14:25:04.264 3438-3438/com.appdynamics.pmdemoapps.android.ECommerceAndroid E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
10-25 14:25:04.264 3438-3438/com.appdynamics.pmdemoapps.android.ECommerceAndroid E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
10-25 14:25:04.264 3438-3438/com.appdynamics.pmdemoapps.android.ECommerceAndroid E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905)
10-25 14:25:04.264 3438-3438/com.appdynamics.pmdemoapps.android.ECommerceAndroid E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:700)
10-25 14:25:04.264 3438-3438/com.appdynamics.pmdemoapps.android.ECommerceAndroid E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: AppKey cannot be null or empty
10-25 14:25:04.264 3438-3438/com.appdynamics.pmdemoapps.android.ECommerceAndroid E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.appdynamics.eumagent.runtime.Instrumentation.a(Instrumentation.java:585)
10-25 14:25:04.264 3438-3438/com.appdynamics.pmdemoapps.android.ECommerceAndroid E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.appdynamics.eumagent.runtime.Instrumentation.a(Instrumentation.java:291)
10-25 14:25:04.264 3438-3438/com.appdynamics.pmdemoapps.android.ECommerceAndroid E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.appdynamics.eumagent.runtime.Instrumentation.start(Instrumentation.java:245)
10-25 14:25:04.264 3438-3438/com.appdynamics.pmdemoapps.android.ECommerceAndroid E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.appdynamics.eumagent.runtime.Instrumentation.start(Instrumentation.java:229)
10-25 14:25:04.264 3438-3438/com.appdynamics.pmdemoapps.android.ECommerceAndroid E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.appdynamics.pmdemoapps.android.ECommerceAndroid.CustomApplication.onCreate(CustomApplication.java:39)
10-25 14:25:04.264 3438-3438/com.appdynamics.pmdemoapps.android.ECommerceAndroid E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1035)
10-25 14:25:04.264 3438-3438/com.appdynamics.pmdemoapps.android.ECommerceAndroid E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4638)
10-25 14:25:04.264 3438-3438/com.appdynamics.pmdemoapps.android.ECommerceAndroid E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:155) 
10-25 14:25:04.264 3438-3438/com.appdynamics.pmdemoapps.android.ECommerceAndroid E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1378) 
10-25 14:25:04.264 3438-3438/com.appdynamics.pmdemoapps.android.ECommerceAndroid E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
10-25 14:25:04.264 3438-3438/com.appdynamics.pmdemoapps.android.ECommerceAndroid E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
10-25 14:25:04.264 3438-3438/com.appdynamics.pmdemoapps.android.ECommerceAndroid E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5343) 
10-25 14:25:04.264 3438-3438/com.appdynamics.pmdemoapps.android.ECommerceAndroid E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
10-25 14:25:04.264 3438-3438/com.appdynamics.pmdemoapps.android.ECommerceAndroid E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
10-25 14:25:04.264 3438-3438/com.appdynamics.pmdemoapps.android.ECommerceAndroid E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905) 
10-25 14:25:04.264 3438-3438/com.appdynamics.pmdemoapps.android.ECommerceAndroid E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:700) 
10-25 14:25:06.342 3438-3438/? I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 3438 SIG: 9
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you ask this question on the AppDynamics forums that can be found here... http://www.appdynamics.com/community/